# How to handle password expiration in WCF service

Tags: wcf, change-password

I have an application with a classic architecture: UI <--> WCF <--> Business layer <--> Data Layer <--> Database. For the WCF service, I use username/password authentication. These usernames are passwords are stored in the application database. The password are configured to expire regularly (business requirement).

I have a problem with password expiration. I have made an operation in my WCF service that is responsible for modifying the user password, but I cannot access it when the password has expired because the authentication failed!

How should I handle that? Should I create a special endpoint with special authentication for password modification (like tolerating access if the password is correct eben though it expired)? It sounds like a heavy solution for such a "small" problem.

EDIT: maybe I should add some more context.
The validation is made in a class implementing UserNamePasswordValidator. In the validate method, I check if the user is locked, if the password is incorrect, if the maximum of login attempts has been reached (if so I also lock the user) and if the password has expired. If one of these is true, the authentication fails.
Maybe it is not the best design...

Comment: Are you having db column which is like a password expiry flag ? If so you can check that before authenticating the password and send a custom exception back and redirect to change password page.

Comment: I have something like that... but that does not help me with how to perform the password change.

Comment: why not?.. you cannot say authentication failed in place of password expiry. I feel this is more of an implementation question rather than a technical question.

Comment: Yes, the more I think about it, the more I believe my design is bad. But I don't really know how to implement it. That's why I edited my question to be more precise about what I do currently. the problem is that if I send an exception during validation, how can i perform a password change?

Comment: Can you in your CustomUserNamePasswordValidator check the requested operation. 
In case the operation is change password, authenticate him based on his username and password only and ignoring other fields in db.

Comment: No, I have no access to the operation itself unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

whenever the password is validated , initially check for password expiry. If password expiry is true , send an exception with a specific error code/error message to the client saying that password has expired. On the client side check the service response for such an error code and redirect the user to the change password page.

Comment: I understand that and it seems valid to me... Except that when I call my password change method, I go through authentication... which throws an exception because the password has expired... and I get in an infinite loop. Maybe I did not explain my design well enough...

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify how you handle permissions in your application, but a user for which the password has expired should be allowed to login but only get permission to change his password.
What we did in a similar situation is to allow the user through the UsernamePasswordValidator but grant him no rights in the AuthorizationPolicy. Since all our functions check for certain permissions the user can't do anything, except changing his password.

Answer (score 1):

Password expiry is an issue with authorization, not authentication. If the password has expired, you should authenticate the user as normal, but you should temporarily fail all authorization checks except the one that allows the user to change password.

NB: No code changes are required in the authentication method, because at the point at which the authentication check is done, the old password is still valid, and thus the user is still authenticated.